# Why is the Sport Equinox taking place more frequently?

Tags: nfl, mlb, nba, nhl

Today, October 20th, 2022 is the 27th time in history that the "Big Four" leagues (NFL, NBA, NHL, MLB) are all in action on the same day.

I've read that there was a 16-year period (1985–2001) without a single Sports Equinox, but now they happen much more frequently. There will be a record four Sports Equinoxes this year.

Comment: Did you happen to read that [here](https://www.axios.com/2022/10/20/sports-equinox-2022-nfl-nba-nhl-mlb-games), by any chance? The wording of your question is uncannily similar to the wording of that article. (It also answers your question, incidentally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but the NBA season starts 11 days earlier comparing between 2002 and 2022.

The article posted by F1Krazy...

> "Thursday Night Football" is a fixture, the World Series starts later,
> and the NBA season starts earlier, they're much more frequent.

...corroborates my statement.